# PHP : best way to get all the elements of an object?

Tags: php

what is the best way to access all the elements of the object instead of using foreach?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `foreach` does not work on objects. Please clarify.

Comment: sure it does. $arr = array("hello"," ","world");
$arr = (Object)$arr;
var_dump($arr);
foreach($arr as $a) {
echo $a;
} ... also.. what is an object in php? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_object_vars` — Gets the properties of the given object

details - http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with foreach?

Well but there are several methods

You could do something like:

```
$length = count($arr);
for($i = 0; $i<$length; $i++)
```

you could also do

```
while($i < $length)
```

and access the items directly if you do have numeric keys.

However foreach won't be slower and its the best way to go if you don't have numeric keys.

You can also access the items using `next($arr)` or you can `push/pop`

I would say it depends on the context what you want to do.

If you want to do X operations with an array of size X for example you need some loop.

If yuo only want to apply the very same operation on all elements you can use the handy function `array_map`

if you just want to get all information from it you could also use `get_object_vars` however, then you have just a new array and what then?

It really depends on the context what you want to do!

In most cases foreach is fine and fast.

If you want to search for specific keys/values or see whether they exists, there are special optimized [array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) for that,.